# git ignores changes on write permissions

Tags: git

I have a file `foo` with permissions 0644 in a repo, already pushed and I would like to change it to 0600.

When I change it locally, git doesn't seem to detect this change. Why?

Thanks

EDIT: I have `filemode = true` in my git config

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes

Comment: This doesn't help. I'm not asking how to solve it as I know git ignores it, I ask why

Comment: It's a designed behaviour, in order to make life easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git is changing my file's permissions when I push to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230171/git-is-changing-my-files-permissions-when-i-push-to-server)

Comment: Thanks, I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230171/git-is-changing-my-files-permissions-when-i-push-to-server
I voted to close the question as duplicate to it