# Why after copying git repository to another dir I have modified files?

Tags: git, copy, repository, commit, copy-paste

I have my personal small git repository on my laptop. I have just commited the changes and checked that I have nothing to commit - every staged and modified file has been commited.

After that I have copied all the files from this repo to another location and boom! I have uncommitted changes.

I believe I am missing some fundamental git rules. Can anyone suggest me on that ?

Comment: Do you intend the new copy to be a git repository as well?

Comment: You should include the information that the original repo was on Windows and the copy is on Ubuntu. That makes a big difference. Given this info, I believe parrhoyts' answer is correct.

Comment: Does `git diff` show you actual differences? Or are you just seeing `git status` saying you have changes? You might be running into the fact that the index stores some metadata about each file - the copy has different timestamps than the original, so `git` might report that those files no longer match what the index thinks should be there, even though the contents of the files may still be identical.

Comment: @twalberg `git diff` shows that whole files are different - marking all of the lines with `+` and again with `-`. I assume that the problem with line endings.

Comment: Facing the same problem, I simply stashed every file sees as modified (the whole app actually) and then trashed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your files on windows probably have carriage-return line-feed line endings and you likely have core.autocrlf true on your windows box. Don't copy it like that between different platforms. Instead create a new git repository on the linux box and pull from the the Windows box. You can either use `git bundle` or `git daemon` on the Windows machine to expose the repository. Or you could make a bare repo on the linux box and `git push --mirror` to it from the Windows machine then clone that where you want the final version to end up.

Or - quite likely you can already just do a `git reset --hard HEAD` and fix it on the linux box as-is. Possibly you should delete everything except the .git folder first to ensure a completely clean working tree.

Answer (score 16):

What I did, run

```
git diff | grep -B 2 @@ | grep +++
```

to get the actually changed files, then do revert on all others

Comment: Worked for me. Shows the files that were actually changed. Then checkout the ones that are listed via git status that don't appear in the git diff

Comment: that didn't work for me for some reason, but I was pretty confident no other whitespace changes would exist, so a `git diff -w` did the trick

Answer (score 5):

If you have nothing on stash to lose, do:

`git checkout .`

This will revert the working tree to your previous commit

Answer (score 2):

Do the permissions between the folders change?
Git will register the change of permissions.

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what do you mean but I have copied files from Win7 machine to Ubuntu if that matters.

Comment: Which file permissions does git track? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071241/how-does-git-handle-folder-permission) suggests it doesn't. Where does your information come from?

Comment: It tracks the executable bit which I think can be set or unset automatically if you access Windows file systems from Ubuntu/linux

Comment: This is correct. It happens due to [permission changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/184/#issuecomment-209777689).

Answer (score 1):

Copying from Windows to Linux introduces a difference in file rights, these changes are also tracked by git.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. However I have copied files from the host linux system to a Virtual Box guest system. Some links get deleted, while some file permissions got changed, which I could fix by doing git config core.filemode false.