# "git blame" a file access control modifier

Tags: git

I noticed that a couple `.txt` files in my git repository have execute permissions. I also noticed that when I did `chmod a-x *.txt` the repo actually showed changes. Here is the output of the `git diff` after updating the files.

```
diff --git a/requirements.txt b/requirements.txt
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

Is there a way to blame permissions of a file? (specifically I'd like to find out who added the `a+x` permissions to these files.

Comment: `git blame` does not look at permissions, only contents. Use [ArturFH's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598709/1256452), since that lets you run arbitrary tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have probably used `git diff` command with some commits specified to get the results shown in your question. Let's assume the command was:

```
git diff goodcommit..badcommit requirements.txt
```

In case you omitted `..badcommit` part, assume the `badcommit` is `HEAD`. You can easily find the offending commit (and a culprit) by running following sequence of commands:

```
git bisect start badcommit goodcommit
git bisect run test ! -x requirements.txt
```

and wait for finish. At the end you will get a message like:

```
running test ! -x requirements.txt
8088473809f905bd8f3d5825983e8c9fe82b10c6 is the first bad commit
commit 8088473809f905bd8f3d5825983e8c9fe82b10c6
Author: author
Date:   Fri Jun 16 23:05:49 2017 +0100

    commit message
```

To get back to normal work, just run:

```
git bisect reset
```

Answer (score 1):

Git only stores the file contents, and execute bit value. [See this answer for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071274/2344348). So it will not reflect any other permission changes.

You can use:

```
git log --follow -p -- a/requirements.txt
```

to view the history of a file.

Comment: Because my question asks specifically about the execute bit, it seems like your answer kind of misses the mark of what I was asking. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: So you don't care about any other permission bits?

Comment: Right, just like I said in the question

> Is there a way to blame permissions of a file? (specifically I'd like to find out who added the a+x permissions to these files.