# Prevent git pull from changing file permissions and ownership

Tags: git, permissions

I'm working on a Linux environment where i have to change some files permissions and ownership but everytime i do a  `git pull` those permissions and ownerships are changed again. i tried `git config --add core.filemode false` but it doesn't seem to work in this context. Is there a way to prevent git pull from changing file permissions and ownership

Answer (score 1):

The settings for the user account doing the pull will usually determine the permissions of the files written. It's either you, or whatever account the script is running under.

The explanation in another post explains some of it: 
[Permissions Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071241/how-does-git-handle-folder-permission),
and see this: [Question about File Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557106/git-changes-my-file-permissions-upon-checkout).