# why my all index is change in my git project

Tags: git

I am using GitLab for my project repository.
From past few week I have not committed my project hence I was only coder in it.
Now when I am trying to commit my project, it shows me that my all file has made any kind of changes.

So i try `git diff` command: here I am attaching screenshot of what result I got. It is clearly show me that all index file has been changed.

I had tried google to solve problem but I failed in it.
So finally here I am to get solution. I do not want to commit my all files

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For file permission mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257613/6309), clone again your repo after:

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

Then from your new cloned repo, do a

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/old/cloned/repo add .
```

That will import your actual changes into the new cloned repo.

---

If you want to keep your current repo (with its changes) you can see the difference with `git diff`, as I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615117/6309).
Note that [since Git 2.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285435/6309), you can change the permission of a file with

```
git add --chmod=-x .
```

Comment: `git --work-dir=/path/to/old/cloned/repo add .` is not working

Comment: You can type it from any folder: it is a global configuration that will apply to all git repositories.

Comment: Unknown option: --work-dir=/home/hardik/lampstack-5.6.26-2/apache2/htdocs/WhitePanda-v3.0-Collaboration/   this is message i get

Comment: @hardik sorry, it was `git --work-tree`, not `--work-dir`. I have fixed the typo in the answer.

Comment: git --work-tree is also showing me error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` this is what i am getting

Comment: It needs to be executed from your newly cloned repo