# Git was roll backed to previous version due to SSD Fail

Tags: git, github, ssh

My dedicated server crashed a day ago due to SSD failure. The hosting company restored my server to 2 days old backup.

The git on the build is now comparing the current changes to 2 days old changes and tracking the newly created files as `deleted`. How can I resync the build on my server to the latest build on git?

Answer (score 0):

With the sequence of actions you mention, if you had some extra modifications on your master branch during the 2 days, you have deleted them from your master branch.

Fortunately, if this was the case, you can still find your commits from your local repo :

1. run `git reflog master`

   you should see an output looking like :

   ```
   110f738 (HEAD -> master, bare/master) master@{0}: reset: moving to origin/master
   224e68f master@{1}: commit: **commit message**    # <- this commit
   1a58e62 master@{2}: commit: **commit message**
   ...
   ```
2. You can use the hash of the commit appearing right before the `reset: moving to origin/master` line

   running for example :

   ```
   # assuming you are on your local 'master' branch :

   # re-set master to its previous state :
   git reset 224e68f

   # push it to your server :
   git push origin master
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A non destructive sequence of actions would be :

1. Fetch all changes :

   ```
   git fetch --all
   ```
2. Update the remote master branch :

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```
3. Update any other relevant branch :

   ```
   git push origin my/feature1
   git push origin my/bugfix
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Following fixed my issue (considering master is your branch):

1. First fetch all changes:

   `git fetch --all`
2. Then reset the master:

   `git reset --hard origin/master`
3. Pull/update:

   `git pull origin/master`

Ref: [Git Pull While Ignoring Local Changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157189/git-pull-while-ignoring-local-changes)

Comment: warning : this sequence of actions will also delete the changes you have made locally since the restore date