# Wrong git commit to trunk in local, how to pull clean from remote?

Tags: git, git-reset

After doing some changes I committed them locally to the trunk before branching. I then branched and pushed my changes to the remote repository.
Now the remote repository has the changes it needs to have. However, because of my local commit to trunk I get the following message when trying to pull recent changes from the remote trunk: `hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.`

I have seen this question  [How to `git pull` while ignoring local changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157189/how-to-git-pull-while-ignoring-local-changes) and I performed the following commands suggested in the answer:

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

However, I'm still getting the same message.

**What did I try and what was I expecting?**
I would like to have my local trunk up to date with remote, and I would like the remote to overwrite all the changes I might have locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the specific command that resets the local trunk and let the local pull an up-to-date version of the remote trunk, without considering the local changes:

```
git reset --hard origin/{trunkName}
```

Comment: What are you supposed to type in place of `{trunkName}` here? The name of your branch? What's wrong with `@{u}`? It's branch-agnostic.

Comment: Exactly, if only one branch diverged from remote, like mentioned in the question, I can reset only this branch. Using `@{u}` I resets all branches.

Comment: "Exactly"? **Absolutely not.** `git reset --hard @{u}` only resets *current local branch* to *the single remote-tracking branch linked to current local branch*.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the local branch in the same position as the remote:

```
git branch -f some-branch some-remote/some-branch
```

As a side note, you should consider avoid using a local branch that is just a tracking mirror of the remote one. You can do operations against the remote branch just as easily.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got the following error after doing this command: `fatal: cannot force update the branch '...' checked out at '/Users/.../Documents/...'`. I also don't understand your side note. Maybe I used wrong terminology in my question. Aren't all branches tracking mirrors of remote branches? And doesn't all push operations automatically done against the remote?

Comment: The error means that you have that local branch checked out in a working tree.... so, go to that working tree and run: `git reset --hard some-remote/some-branch`which will it to the place it should be (it's a hard reset so you will lose any uncommitted changes.... committed changes are fine, they can be retrieved with the reflog in case you think you messed up). And **_no_**, those are assumptions probably based on following pre-cooked recipes for a long time. Repos/Branches are **completely** independent... and each can have an _upstream_  that is used to automate some things.

Comment: By the way, I see I left something out there: _Repos/Branches are completely independent... and each **local branch** can have an upstream that is used to automate some things_.

Answer (score 2):

From you local branch, with a clean working tree, you could do a simple (branch-agnostic)

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

`@{u}` is a specific construct in git, which means "the ref set for this branch as the default pull source" (see [the part](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) of the git revisions page where it's described)

*Note: Before you reset, be sure to `git fetch` to get fresh remote references or you could still be behind the remote (because of what your local repo "knows" so far).*