# Git and egit conflict about file mode 10064 although filemode is set to false

Tags: eclipse, git, msysgit, egit

Resembles to

1. [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod?rq=1)
2. [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/removing-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-changes-in)

but is most likely a different problem.

System is win7 x64.

## The problem

Although filemode is false, msysgit keeps keeps seeing changes with `deleted file mode 100644` or `new file mode 100644` although the filemode is set to false:

```
[core]
    filemode = false
```

According to egit there are no changes. I can commit from msysgit, but that makes egit think there are changes, and committing amend from egit exits with

> 'Committing changes' has encountered a problem. An internal error
>   occured.
>    No changes.

I don't understand this mess, since filemode is clearly set to false...

**I don't care about filemodes but want to use egit and msysgit.

How do i get out of this trap?**

Comment: Which Egit version and msysgit version are you using?

Comment: `egit 1.3.0` and `git-gui version 0.13.GITGUI git version 1.7.7.1.msysgit.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow i was able to get rid of this problem by repeatedly amend commiting from both git-gui and eclipse egit. I also staged the unstaged file mode changes before making such commits.

Sorry, i can't make this answer more satisficing. Hope this helps someone.