# What does it mean when Git diff shows mode changes?

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm trying to view changes for a single file that is unstaged.

First I use `git status` to view all the unstaged changes then for example:

```
git diff AndroidManifest.xml
```

But I get this output:

```
diff --git a/AndroidManifest.xml b/AndroidManifest.xml  
old mode 100755  
new mode 100644
```

What does that mean and how can I view changes for specific file?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Most probably, the contents of this file haven't changed, only the executable bit has been cleared. Try actually changing the file by, say, appending an empty line to it, and see what `git diff` outputs.

Apart from file contents, Git also records the state of the executable bit for each file. It makes sense on Linux systems if you want scripts to be executable right after checkout. See also the following two related questions:

[How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580596/946850)

[How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1257592/946850)

Comment: Yes you are right, i made a changed to file and now it shows difference. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

It means that the file mode changed from 755 to 644, but the contents were not altered.

`git diff` is exactly what you are looking for - it shows the changes from unstaged files to the last commit. `git diff --cached` is for staged files.

Comment: Can I avoid this file mode change?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Sure, of course. Git does not change the file mode, it only tracks that the mode change happened. Either simply change it back to its original mode or don't change it in the first place.