# how to deal with dropbox's influence on file modes ?

Tags: git, unix

I use dropbox to store all my code, mostly rails ruby and web stuff.  i just went through an evolution where I had to change the location of where dropbox was storing files on my local system.  throughout all my git repositories in the dropbox directory, which are numerous, my git status commands are telling me the below,

```
diff --git a/.flooignore b/.flooignore
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/.sublime-project b/.sublime-project
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

How should I change the file permissions all across the entire dropbox directory to return things to the way they were before I had to make changes that led to this state ?

I'm on a mac osx with mountain lion 10.8.5

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1257592/113848), which unfortunately doesn't seem to have a definitive answer.