# GIT Diff is saying 100644 → 100755 on many files

Tags: git, github, file-permissions

Heres whats going on:
I am on a mac and in the terminal, I am executing a git pull to a main branch.  Al those files come to my local directory and for some reason the permissions are being changed to this:      -rwxr-xr-x@ when it should be this: -rw-r--r--. So, when I push these files up to my local branch on github and try to submit a pull request to the main, many files say show this: 100644 → 100755.

I've tried [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha) , but still no luck.

I tried to download the files from the main branch as a zip and replace all my local files but no luck again.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion would be that you figure out why the permissions are being changed to begin with, rather than trying to figure out how to make `git` ignore or otherwise deal with the changes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha)

Answer (score 1):

please try the command as following.
git config --add core.filemode false

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with commands. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: `core.fileMode` is not the best practice and should be used carefully!. Refer to detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580644/3048967) .