# Changing File Mode permissions from 100755 to 100644 on GITHUB

Tags: git, file, github, mode, git-config

I changed permissions of some files locally and pushed it to GITHUB without having the config.FileMode flag = false in my gitconfig. So GIT Pushed the file mode changes but I want to revert those file mode changes from 100755 to 100644.I am using a MAC osx as my development environment. I don't want to use git reset --hard HEAD on my repository. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You would need to do `git reset --hard HEAD~` to revert committed changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha)

Answer (score 10):

In my case just changing the permission manually from 755 to 644 worked and pushing it again to GITHUB.

```
chmod 644 <filename>
```

GIT will list this file in the diff and you can simply commit and push it to your repository on GITHUB.

Comment: I want to do this for all files in my repo but keep the executable files executable.

Answer (score 1):

I changed permission of my files manually from 755 to 644 using the below mentioned command and pushed the files again.

```
chmod -x <file_name>
```

After pushing the files, I changed `core.filemode` config to false so that permission of other files don't get changed.