# git - confusion over terminology, "theirs" vs "mine"

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

I'm completely confused about what mine vs theirs means. In this specific case, I've got a feature branch where I just squashed about 80 commits via `rebase -i` and am merging this back into `develop`. I got a few conflicts, and I just want to use whatever code is on my feature branch. I tried "mine" but that actually seemed to do the opposite.

Could someone shed some light on this terminology?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`ours` and `theirs` is a somewhat confusing concept; exacerbated when performing a rebase:

When performing a merge, `ours` refers to the branch you're merging *into*, and `theirs` refers to the branch you are merging *from*. So if you are trying to resolve conflicts in the middle of a *merge*:

- use `ours` to accept changes from the branch we are currently on
- use `theirs` to accept changes from the branch we are merging into.

That makes sense, right?

When *rebasing*, `ours` and `theirs` are inverted. Rebases pick files into a "detached" HEAD branch. The target is that HEAD branch, and `merge-from` is the original branch before rebase. That makes:

- `--ours` the anonymous one the rebase is constructing, and
- `--theirs` the one being rebased;

I.e., rebasing replays the current branch's commits (one at a time) on top of the branch that we intend to rebase with.

Comment: You say "theirs refers to the branch you are merging *from*" and then "use theirs to accept changes from the branch we are merging *into*"  - huh?

Comment: Poor use of the term "into". If I'm on a branch, and want to merge with master, running "Git checkout --theirs filename(s)" will give master's files precedence, this overwriting my branch's copies. "--ours" is the opposite, giving my branch precedence in the merge

Comment: Hmm, I find the question which perfectly matches my confusion. I read the well-voted answer several times, and still don't know the answer to any level of confidence. Back to Google.

Comment: @HeyHeyJC I can try to rephrase if you can articulate specifics of what’s unclear

Comment: Confusion comes from 'the branch we are currently on' and 'the branch we are merging into' being the same thing.  I think what you mean for the second one is 'the branch we are merging into the branch we are on'.  I think a clearer way of saying the second case is 'to accept the changes from the branch you are merging'

Comment: All contradictory answers. When you are in Gitlab making a merge from a branch comparison, you are not actually "into" any branch in particular, at least you don't explicitly know. "Source" and "target" branch would be more explicit terms when you are not using the command line.

Answer (score 24):

"Ours" (and "mine") refer to the *current* branch; "theirs" refers to the branch being merged in. It sounds like you actually wanted to use "theirs".

Comment: sometimes, straight forward answer is great. UP vote

Comment: i think it is the opposite.

Answer (score -1):

I admit it is confusing at first . I even wrote [an article](https://eekayonline.medium.com/git-repos-mine-vs-theirs-explained-4467a46ccbb0) about this to explain in detail how this works.

In short: "mine" is the change you're holding in your branch, "theirs" is the target branch that everything is going into.