# Very stange git rebase behavior

Tags: git, rebase

I'm no Git expert, but I can't understand a strange behavior of the `git rebase` in my case:
1. create a local empty git reposiory using `git init`
2. create a simple text file **file.txt** with the following content:

```
111
222
333
```

3. add **file.txt** to the index using `git add file.txt` and commit changes using `git commit`
4. switch to a new branch using `git checkout -b feature`
5. change **file.txt** so now it has the following content:

```
111
333
```

6. add **file.txt** to the index using `git add file.txt` and commit changes using `git commit`
7. change **file.txt** so now it has the following content:

```
111
444
333
```

8. add **file.txt** to the index using `git add file.txt` and commit changes using `git commit`
9. switch to the master branch using git checkout master; now **file.txt** has the following content:

```
111
222
333
```

10. change **file.txt** so now it has the following content:

```
111
777
222
333
```

11. add **file.txt** to the index using `git add file.txt` and commit changes using `git commit`
12. change **file.txt** so now it has the following content:

```
111
777
222
888
333
```

13. add **file.txt** to the index using `git add file.txt` and commit changes using `git commit`
14. switch to the feature branch using git checkout feature; now **file.txt** has the following content:

```
111
444
333
```

15. rebase **feature** branch onto the **master** branch using `git rebase master`; now I have a conflict in **file.txt** and that file has the following content:

```
111
<<<<<<< HEAD
777
222
888
=======
>>>>>>> 2
333
```

instead of expected:

```
111
<<<<<<< HEAD
777
222
888
=======
444
>>>>>>> 2
333
```

So my question is: why did the text `444` disappear from the **file.txt**? Is it ok?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. Is it possible to simplify it and get similar behavior?

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817210/git-confusion-over-terminology-theirs-vs-mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you do `git rebase master`:

1. The work tree is reset to `master`
2. The commits after the fork point in the current branch are applied one by one

The conflict in your example happens on the very first commit in `feature` after the fork point. This is the commit where you deleted the line with `222`.

> So my question is: why did the text 444 disappear from the file.txt? Is it ok?

It did not disappear. *It did not appear yet.* After you resolve this conflict and `rebase --continue`, it will come in the next commit.