# Which file is mine vs theirs when using git merge?

Tags: git

As an ex SVN user, how do I tell git I want mine or theirs? Head and MERGE HEAD do not make any sense to me. I want the version I am pulling from the server to overwrite the one on my computer is that HEAD or MERGE HEAD?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git - confusion over terminology, "theirs" vs "mine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817210/git-confusion-over-terminology-theirs-vs-mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mine` is code as it is on your branch *during a merge* (operations like `rebase` can change what `mine` means).  To elaborate on git terminology, specially given that your background is from svn, `HEAD` is **always** where you are... which is not the same as *the last revision*, as in svn. If you checkout master~5, `HEAD` is right there, 5 revisions behind master. `MERGE_HEAD` is what you asked to merge... in other words, *the other branch/revision*.

Now, case in point, if you just want to take a file as it is in `MERGE_HEAD`, you can do

```
git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- path-to-file
```

That will add it to index, on top of setting it that way in your working tree.

Answer (score 0):

When git merge, If you catch conflict, you will see something like

```
>>>>>mines
bazz
fuu
>>>>>

>>>>>theirs
foo
bar
>>>>>
```

If no conflict, you can use command `git blame`, for example

```
git blame path/to/file.ext
```

to see what line(s) of code are yours, what are theirs.

Example of blame on GitHub web GUI: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blame/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-activemq/build.gradle

Reference document: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame