# Git issues with shared folders in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, centos6

I have never seen this issue before while using Vagrant, so I'm hoping this makes sense to someone. I have a folder that contains a git repository, that is being synced with a Vagrant machine running CentOS 6.5, and seeing some inconsistencies with Git.

On my host machine (Mac OSX) if I run `git status` I get the following:

```
 ~/Folder/repo$ git status
 On branch master
 Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
 nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But if I run the same command within my vagrant box, I get the following:

```
vagrant@localhost ~/repo$ git status                                                                                                                 master
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .codeclimate.yml
#   modified:   .gitattributes
#   modified:   .gitignore
#   modified:   CONTRIBUTING.md
#   modified:   app/commands/.gitkeep
#   modified:   app/commands/CreateModule.php
#   modified:   app/commands/FbAdRevenue.php
....
```

And the list goes on, basically git locally seems to think that every single file has been modified and not committed which is not true. Any idea why this would be the case and how to fix it?

Comment: 1) Make sure your OSX machine is setup to see the remote host, for updates. `git remote -v`
2) Do a local diff `git diff HEAD^^ <file>` and see what it thinks changed. Sometimes timezone issue could cause all your files to show as being different.

Comment: Good to go on item one @NeerPatel. Ran the git diff command and the only thing it shows is that the mode has changed from 100644 to 100755

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information after you ran the `diff`, it looks like file permissions changed on the server.

Use the following command to ignore permissions

`git config core.filemode false`

[How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha)

Comment: I actually wound up changing some configuration in my Vagrant box, and the issue was resolved. But since your solution would work as well, will try to mark this as the accepted issue.

Comment: @HunterSkrasek - Thanks!

Comment: Could you then post your own answer seeing as you fixed it?

Comment: @HunterSkrasek would you mind sharing what Vagrant configuration you adjusted to make it work without changing Git's configuration? we're on the edge of our seats wondering! :]

Comment: I'll try to, this is like a year old and honestly forgot what I did.