# Different git statuses on shared directory repo when accessed from windows vs linux

Tags: git

The scenario is that there is a single git repository (with a working folder) on an IBM i server. That same folder is shared to a Windows machine. The code in that folder was created on the Windows machine, but the repository and the initial check-in was done via git on the server. (The git client on that server is essentially a linux version).

Now, when i view git status from the git client on the server, the working directory shows as having no changes.  However, if i use the git client on my Windows machine, i see every file has being changed. 
I initially thought this had to do with the core.autocrlf setting, but i turned off that feature in the Windows git client(autocrlf=false) and it was not set at all in the server's git config.

Can anyone explain why i am seeing two different results from the two git clients?

FYI, i must use the git client on the server because the git commands have to integrate with a more comprehensive change management solution on that server. However, using git from Windows is more convenient since i can make use of git GUIs on Windows, and that will help with introducing git to the rest of the team.

Comment: What's the output of `git diff`? Is it just the line endings?

Comment: i'm seeing (for each file): old mode 100755  (and on next line) new mode 100644

Comment: Sounds like a permissions change. In other words, the tracked change is just that the permissions on each file has changed.

Comment: yeah, i found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha    trying that solution now. if it works, will update this question to point to that

Comment: btw, mwm314, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad to help! Just be careful (see my answer below). Make sure to read the other link I have in my answer, it's a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like git is tracking a permissions change for every file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes) for how to not make git track file permissions. Summarizing the answer, you likely want to do `git config --global core.filemode false`. To make sure this is the issue, execute `git -c core.filemode=false diff`. You should (hopefully) see an empty diff.

A word of warning: If you have tight security practices, this is likely something you don't want to do. It might be better to just accept/track the file permissions changes.

Comment: point taken. will look into the cause of why those files have the executable bit set - they probably shouldn't, and will probably update the files properly to avoid the issue altogether