# How to restore the permissions of files and directories within git if they have been modified?

Tags: git, file, file-permissions

I have a git checkout. All the file permissions are different than what git thinks they should be therefore they all show up as modified.

Without touching the content of the files (just want to modify the permissions) how do I set all the files permissions to what git thinks they should be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha)

Answer (score 747, accepted):

Git keeps track of filepermission and exposes permission changes when creating patches using `git diff -p`. So all we need is:

1. create a reverse patch
2. include only the permission changes
3. apply the patch to our working copy

As a one-liner (run from the repository's root directory):

```
git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color --diff-filter=M \
    | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never  \
    | git apply
```

you can also add it as an alias to your git config...

```
git config --global --add alias.permission-reset '!git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color --diff-filter=M | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never | git apply'
```

...and you can invoke it via:

```
git permission-reset
```

Note, if you shell is `bash`, make sure to use `'` instead of `"` quotes around the `!git`, otherwise it gets substituted with the last `git` command you ran.

Thx to @Mixologic for pointing out that by simply using `-R` on `git diff`, the cumbersome `sed` command is no longer required.

Comment: I'm in OS X, this is not working. I've identified the problem is in the git apply. It doesn't apply the file permissions changes.

Comment: Oh, it worked, I was trying to apply from a directory different than the repository root. git apply only works there.

Comment: Is there some reason you wouldnt just do "git diff -p -R" instead of doing the sed's to make it reverse?

Comment: @Mixologic no. Looks like I just missed it. ;-) ...will update the answer.

Comment: Please note that this ofcourse also reverts changes inside of the file. I needed to update files (compiled js files) so the content changes should stay, but the file permissions were messed up. The answer of Tim Henigan below fixed my permission changes, by ignoring them (yeah i'm forced to use windows :( )

Comment: @RobQuist my local changes weren't removed when using muhqu's command

Comment: I'm getting `fatal: unrecognized input`

Comment: Oh, that was caused by staged changes. `git reset` before calling command helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I faced the same `fatal: unrecognized input` message. Turns out my color settings were set to 'always', which caused the color escape chars to be part of the output even when piping or writing to a file.
Changing from 'always' to 'auto' did the trick.

Comment: @AVIDeveloper thanks for pointing out. maybe you can leave it 'always' when you just add `--no-color` to the `git diff` command?

Comment: @muhqu - that was my first attempt, but it didn't work out because, running from cygwin I have GNU Grep which doesn't support that flag. I now found that it has a `--color=never` option that does the trick, so... cool! I anyway think that 'auto' is a better color option for grep so I'll stick with that. Thanks!

Comment: @AVIDeveloper ur welcome, i updated the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: @muhqu Alright. I just checked under Ubuntu and `--color=never` is actually the correct grep flag, so this is not just Win/GNU specific. Great!

Comment: `git diff -p` doesn't always report all discrepancies

Comment: Re `fatal: unrecognized input` - if you already staged your changes (you are in the middle of an interactive rebase for instance ready to hit continue) add `--cached` to the git diff command

Comment: this is what I have tried      git diff -p -R --no-color --cached | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never  | git apply       Still get 'fatal: unrecognized input"  I have tried all the tricks mentioned above, git reset...  The result of my     git diff -p -R --no-color --cached | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never  | git apply   is     diff --git b/file1.out   a/file1.out      is that expected?

Comment: @gigi2 the diff should include lines starting with "diff", "new mode" and "old mode". If the new/old mode lines are missing then either git doesn't know about the permissions or there are no differences to them... Hope that helps.

Comment: @Torek - Another +1 to the Git developers for taking a simple task, and making it ridiculously complicated. God forbid they allow `git checkout <file>` actually work as expected.

Comment: the command given above may work for some, but not if you have external diff configured, 
in that case add `--no-ext-diff`
like this:
`git diff -p -R --no-color --no-ext-diff \
    | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never  \
    | git apply`

Comment: Change these commands to `git -c core.fileMode=true ...` to ensure they'll work even in environments where global or local options have disabled checking the file modes.

Comment: git apply fails silently for me

Comment: If you're getting `fatal: unrecognized input`, you may have applied `git config core.fileMode false` which is suggested below. You should set `git config core.fileMode true` before running the above command!

Comment: `fatal: unrecognized input` can also be due to `git diff` not outputting any results for me this was because I was attempting to fix the previous commit another developer made.  The finished result for fixing the last commit looked like this on a mac `git diff -p -R --no-color --no-ext-diff HEAD^ HEAD | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never | git apply` NOTE: the `HEAD^ HEAD` was what I was missing.

Comment: In case you run into `error: unrecognized input` it might be that stdin `git apply` for apply is empty, i.e. there are no permission changes in this repo. Especially when recursively applying it to submodules, it can be handy to replace `git apply` by `ifne git apply` using `ifne` from `moreutils` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/ifne.1.html

Comment: dont' know why, after running the `>> As a one-liner:` part, the files are removed.

Comment: If anybody is trying this with a dirty git submodule - the script crashes, but I fixed it by first running the script in the submodule, stashing any changes, then running it in the main repo and then manually unstashing changes. Easy peasy.

Comment: If I want to rever file change permission from an specific commit?

Comment: does this reset to last commit only? Since commit looks like not specified

Answer (score 186):

Try `git config core.fileMode false`

From the [`git config`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html) man page:

> `core.fileMode`
>
> If false, the executable bit differences between the index and the working copy are ignored; useful on broken filesystems like FAT. See [git-update-index(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).
>
> The default is true, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probe and set core.fileMode false if appropriate when the repository is created.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing. Very used to cvs not tracking permissions so this works.

Comment: @shovas: I am glad this helped.  I experienced a similar issue when sharing repos between Linux and Windows.  BTW: if this answered your question, please mark the response as correct.

Comment: Is it possible that `git checkout origin/master` sets file permissions committed to the server to my local working copy? Because whenever I build V8 for ArangoDB, the file permissions are changed so that access is denied to the entire build folder (even with elevated rights; Windows 7+ that is). I need to fix all local file permissions before I can continue the build process. Can `core.filemode false` fix that too? I suspect git to set Linux permissions on my Windows machine. The build scripts might just preserve them and apply the same permissions to newly created files...

Comment: Im wondering if there's any downside to setting `filemode` to `false` !

Answer (score 10):

Git doesn't store file permissions other than executable scripts. Consider using something like [git-cache-meta](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) to save file ownership and permissions.

Git can only store two types of modes:  755 (executable) and 644 (not executable).  If your file was 444 git would store it has 644.

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. Git does, indeed, track permissions.

Comment: It's roughly accurate, see https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ContentLimitations. The exact permissions that get set appear to based on the server & possibly the client `umask` as well as a config setting, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12735291/125150.

Comment: @Will no, it doesn't. Can't believe your comment got so many upvotes.

Comment: @Will, this is roughly correct. Per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

`...a mode of 100644, which means it’s a normal file. Other options are 100755, which means it’s an executable file; and 120000, which specifies a symbolic link. The mode is taken from normal UNIX modes but is much less flexible — these three modes are the only ones that are valid for files (blobs) in Git (although other modes are used for directories and submodules).`

Answer (score 10):

```
git diff -p \
| grep -E '^(diff|old mode|new mode)' \
| sed -e 's/^old/NEW/;s/^new/old/;s/^NEW/new/' \
| git apply
```

will work in most cases but if you have external diff tools like meld installed you have to add --no-ext-diff

```
git diff --no-ext-diff -p \
    | grep -E '^(diff|old mode|new mode)' \
    | sed -e 's/^old/NEW/;s/^new/old/;s/^NEW/new/' \
    | git apply
```

was needed in my situation

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @muhqu for his great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4408378/2285882). In my case not all changes files had permissions changed which prevented the command to work.

```
$ git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never
diff --git b/file1 a/file1
diff --git b/file2 a/file2
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
$ git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never | git apply
warning: file1 has type 100644, expected 100755
```

The patch would then stop and files would be left untouched.

In case some people have similar problem I solved this by tweaking the command to grep only files with permission changed:

```
grep -E "^old mode (100644|100755)" -B1 -A1
```

or for the git alias

```
git config --global --add alias.permission-reset '!git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color | grep -E "^old mode (100644|100755)" -B1 -A1 --color=never | git apply'
```

Answer (score 3):

i know this is old, but i came from google and i didn't find an answer

i have a simple solution **if you have no change you want to keep** :

```
git config core.fileMode true
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar problem, someone added the executable flag to all the files on the server, however I also had local modified files besides the ones with the broken permissions. However, since the only permission git tracks is the executable flag, this pipeline fixed the problem for me:

```sh
git status | grep 'modified:' | awk '{print $3}' | xargs chmod a-x
```

Basically the command runs git status, filters the files reported as modifier, extracts their path via `awk`, and removes the executable flag.

Comment: In general grep + awk can preferably be simplified to just awk (e.g. `awk '/modified/{print $3}'`), although this solution will not properly handle spaces in file names. Fortunately there is a native git equivalent that does: `git ls-files -m -z | xargs -0 chmod a-x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4408378/6309), using `git apply`

```bash
git diff -p -R --no-ext-diff --no-color --diff-filter=M \
    | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never  \
    | git apply
```

Make sure to use With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2082dbdd315aa4dd3f315545e5b3ab3b3e2d894), "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf47fb7ec7e183a1a1e521a540862fba3c2a89eb/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> on a filesystem without filemode support have learned to take a hint from what is in the index for the path, even when not working with the "`--index`" or "`--cached`" option, when checking the executable bit match what is required by the preimage in the patch.

See [commit 45b6251](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45b625142d8ca2218af1fb2b37216e58953e775d), [commit 01aff0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01aff0ae85af100c4d88df753078158b82774ea0) (26 Dec 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 0482c32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0482c32c334b046ff2dd2190c026cfd4ec564233) (26 Dec 2023) by [Chandra Pratap (`Pratapchandradeo`)](https://github.com/Pratapchandradeo).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cf47fb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf47fb7ec7e183a1a1e521a540862fba3c2a89eb), 26 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0482c32c334b046ff2dd2190c026cfd4ec564233): ignore working tree filemode when `!core.filemode`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Chandra Pratap</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When applying a patch that adds an executable file, [`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0482c32c334b046ff2dd2190c026cfd4ec564233/Documentation/git-apply.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> ignores the core.fileMode setting (core.fileMode in [`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0482c32c334b046ff2dd2190c026cfd4ec564233/Documentation/git-config.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> specifies whether the executable bit on files in the working tree should be honored or not) resulting in warnings like:
>
> ```
> warning: script.sh has type 100644, expected 100755
> ```
>
> even when `core.fileMode` is set to `false`, which is undesired.
> This is extra true for systems like Windows.
>
> Fix this by inferring the correct file mode from either the existing index entry, and when it is unavailable, assuming that the file mode was OK by pretending it had the mode that the preimage wants to see, when `core.filemode` is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a pre/post checkout hook might do the trick.

See: [Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Answer (score 0):

`git diff -p` used in [muhqu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4408378/648265) may not show all discrepancies.

- saw this in Cygwin for files I didn't own
- mode changes are ignored completely if `core.filemode` is `false` (which is the default for MSysGit)

This code reads the metadata directly instead:

```bash
(set -o errexit pipefail nounset;
git ls-tree HEAD -z | while read -r -d $'\0' mask type blob path
do
    if [ "$type" != "blob" ]; then continue; fi;
    case "$mask" in
    #do not touch other bits
    100644) chmod a-x "$path";;
    100755) chmod a+x "$path";;
    *) echo "invalid: $mask $type $blob\t$path" >&2; false;;
    esac
done)
```

A non-production-grade one-liner (replaces masks entirely):

```bash
git ls-tree HEAD | perl -ne '/^10(0\d{3}) blob \S+\t(.+)$/ && { system "chmod",$1,$2 || die }'
```

<sub><sub>(Credit for "$'\0'" goes to http://transnum.blogspot.ru/2008/11/bashs-read-built-in-supports-0-as.html)</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

I use git from cygwin on Windows, the `git apply` solution doesn't work for me. Here is my solution, run `chmod` on every file to reset its permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for c in `git diff -p |sed -n '/diff --git/{N;s/diff --git//g;s/\n/ /g;s# a/.* b/##g;s/old mode //g;s/\(.*\) 100\(.*\)/chmod \2 \1/g;p}'`
do
        eval $c
done
unset IFS
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest thing to do is to just change the permissions back.  As @kroger noted git only tracks executable bits.  So you probably just need to run `chmod -x filename` to fix it (or `+x` if that's what's needed.

Comment: Here's an example from `git show`:

diff --git a/OpenWatch/src/org/ale/openwatch/fb/FBUtils.java b/OpenWatch/src/org/ale/openwatch/fb/FBUtils.java
index cd6fa6a..e5b0935 **100644**

That bit in bold there is the file permissions.

Comment: This seemed easiest to me, too. Unfortunately, I encountered the same problem as Conrado - I could not change permission from `100644` to `100755`. I don't think you deserve a downvote; Git should be down voted. It is so broken in so many ways at so many different levels...

Answer (score -3):

The [`etckeeper` tool](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper) can handle permissions and with:

```
etckeeper init -d /mydir
```

You can use it for other dirs than `/etc`.

Install by using your package manager or get sources from above link.

Comment: What does it set permissions to? If it doesn't read Git metadata or invoke Git, it doesn't do what the OP requested.