# Prevent Git from changing permissions on pull

Tags: git, version-control

When I pull change from my repositories, Git change the file permissions (actually, he change the group `write` permission).

If I'm correct, Git should only track executable bit and this anyway can be removed using setting `core.filemode` to false.

But, although the filemode is set to false (in local, global and user), when I pull, `write` permission constantly change.

I could use a git-hooks in order to reset correct chmod, but this is some overhead and I'd prefer if there's a way to just ask git to completly ignore file mode change.

Anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517339/how-to-restore-the-permissions-of-files-and-directories-within-git-if-they-have

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One config setting that *might* help here is [`core.sharedRepository`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), presented in the blog post "[Preserving Group Write on Git Objects in a Collaborative Repository](http://briantanaka.com/blog/git/)":

> The solution turned out to be fairly straightforward.
> In the file `.git/config`, I added a line that read: "`sharedRepository = group`", like so:
>
> ```
> [core]
>     repositoryformatversion = 0
>     filemode = true
>     bare = false
>     logallrefupdates = true
>     sharedRepository = group
> ```
>
> Thereafter, new files in `.git/objects` were created with the proper permissions for group write.
> (However, note that new files are group-owned by the primary group of the user account via which the push was received. If the users collaborating on the project have different primary groups, and if those users do not share membership in that set of groups, you may still run into problems.)

Make sure of the **value of your `umask`**:

> Example: `0660` will make the repo read/write-able for the owner and group, but inaccessible to others (equivalent to group unless `umask` is e.g. `0022`).

---

2022 (10 years later), [SyedAsadRazaDevops](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16359307/syedasadrazadevops) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733452/prevent-git-from-changing-permissions-on-pull#comment129865979_12735291):

> In Ubuntu (Linux), just go to the project repo and run this command `nano .git/config` and add `sharedRepository = group` in `[core]` section.

That would be the same as:

```bash
cd /path/to/repo
git config core.sharedRepository group
```

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/repo-discuss/QrJII6gTLGM on the `umask` (or http://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine)

Comment: Hey thanks! My trouble wasn't about .git/objects, but files into the repo, but your comment on the `umask` was right. Setting the `umask` to `002` allowed group write access by default.

Comment: in ubuntu (Linux), just go to the project repo and run this command `nano .git/config` and add `sharedRepository = group` in **[core]** section, thankyou @VonC                   @syedasadrazadevops

Comment: @SyedAsadRazaDevops Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 10):

The solution I use is to [run the command as the user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password) that has the permissions you want to keep:

```
sudo -u user command
```

In this case, it could be:

```
sudo -u www-data git pull
```

`www-data` [being the apache default user on Ubuntu at least](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520634/giving-ownership-of-the-directory-to-the-apache-user).

This keeps the permissions from changing. I use it when updating git repositories on my VPS, while keeping the file permissions set to the webserver user.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to test that. +1

Comment: Also have to share private key with user www-data for this to work

Comment: Best and quick solution.