# How can I stop (not ignore) Git from changing filemode when working on a repository in both Windows and Linux?

Tags: git

In most cases just ignoring the changes is probably enough, but I have a few repos where the filemode changes need to be tracked.

What I'm looking for is a way to stop the automatic change that happens in different operating systems on check out. If I check out the repo on Windows it sets the filemode to 0755 and flags all files as changed in git status. If I check the same repo out on Linux it behaves the same except they are set to 0644 which is what they should be. How can I make Windows keep the 0644 permissions on checkout/in?

The only workaround I know of would be to keep (and maintain) a set of scripts to manually set the permissions, but that shouldn't be needed since the functionality is already there.

Comment: You're question doesn't seem to match your problem. Maybe remove the git part from it? The last question seems to be more fitting than your headline, at least to my understanding

Comment: The question is entirely related to git. If I do a git pull, it automatically changes the filemode differently depending on the machine I pull from and I need to stop this behavior.

Comment: Would this Q&A help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733452/prevent-git-from-changing-permissions-on-pull

Comment: Maybe explain what permission 0755 on Windows means, specifically as NTFS (FAT neither) does not have such permissions natively.