# Git pull causes files/folders to have file permission of Group: Write. How to stop this?

Tags: wordpress, git, file-permissions, git-pull

Whenever I do a git pull on my server, the file permissions for both files and folders have Group: Write enabled. Making files 664, and folders 775. I'm using git for version control on my Wordpress projects and due to Group: Write being enabled on all files, it's causing a 500 internal server error.

Is there a way for git to stop adding the Group: Write permission to the files and folders?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517339/git-how-to-recover-the-file-permissions-git-thinks-the-file-should-be

Comment: Thanks for that. Changing umask to 0022 seemed to work. I'm not sure if that is the correct way but for now it will do.