# Why are files showing as modified in GitHub Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I am using the GitHub Atom editor. In the tree view, almost all of the files in my project appear orange even though no files have been modified since my last commit. What else could be causing this?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question. It could be anything from a package you have installed, to a stylesheet change, to random disk cruft, to an actual bug.

Comment: I have not made any modifications to Atom. I just installed it. Could it be related to file permission differences? I have set up git to ignore permissions changes in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was caused by changed file permissions. I tested this out by changing the permissions on some files, which caused them to be displayed as unmodified in Atom.

Comment: To recover file permissions of a git project, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517339/git-how-to-recover-the-file-permissions-git-thinks-the-file-should-be