# git does not recognize the mode of a file

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a file that am tracking with git in a project, whenever i change the mode of the file to anything mode other than granting write access to the file, git ignores those changes ( which is causing a bug in the project ).

for example a file edit.json
if i change the mode with

`chmod 666 edit.json`

git ignores that the mode of the file have changed ( especially if i turn on write access to the file for group and others )

How can i get pass this problem ?

Comment: Git only saves whether a file is executable and/or symlinked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3211396/3001761

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517339/how-to-recover-the-file-permissions-to-what-git-thinks-the-file-should-be

Comment: thanks for answers. I tried them all, but whenever i push my code to a remote branch , the file permission still remain the same

Comment: @0.sh: to amplify (to the point of distortion, but maybe it will do the trick :-) ) jonrsharpe's comment, the fundamental problem is that Git doesn't *store* the mode of the file. You **cannot** make the file a+w through Git itself. You **must** use something other than Git itself to store and set this.