# How to fix "fatal: unrecognized input" when trying set up file permissions?

Tags: git, file, file-permissions

I'm trying to set up file permissions, I refer to this instruction:

[How to recover the file permissions to what git "thinks" the file should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517339/how-to-recover-the-file-permissions-to-what-git-thinks-the-file-should-be?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

When I enter the git command

```
git diff -p -R --no-color \
    | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never  \
    | git apply
```

The console shows me `fatal: unrecognized input`. I'm trying add `--no-color`, `--no-ext-diff` also I put in my gitconfig file this line [`color] ui = auto`, but all of these things are not helping me.

Do you have any ideas for what I need to do ?

Comment: Which command is giving you the `fatal: unrecognized input` error?  Is it `git` or `grep`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Before answered, you must know -  I'm new in git . I'm not sure , but I think it's a git , because grep I already installed. I just copied this piece of code 
    git diff -p -R --no-color \
    | grep -E "^(diff|(old|new) mode)" --color=never  \
    | git apply
and push enter, then console blow me up fatal: unrecognized input

Comment: Look into encoding type