# Why does git reset not undo permission changes?

Tags: git

Someone else asked the question [How to restore the permissions of files and directories within git if they have been modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517339/how-to-restore-the-permissions-of-files-and-directories-within-git-if-they-have) which was answered by using a reverse patch.

Why doesn't `git reset` reset the permissions back to what they were?

Comment: It does for me. Does it not on some platforms?

Comment: If you’re wondering why the answer isn’t just `git reset --hard HEAD`, for example, it’s because of the “Without touching the content of the files” part – the asker seems to want to commit file content changes without committing accidental permission changes.

Comment: It does not seem to work on Windows with NTFS.