# Hide/restore/report all non-content git changes

Tags: git

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4408378/147356:

```
git diff -p |
    grep -E '^(diff|old mode|new mode)' |
    sed -e 's/^old/NEW/;s/^new/old/;s/^NEW/new/' |
    git apply
```

1. I was handed a project in which the previous dev made modifications in production directly
2. I copied everything from production into my git repository, expecting the see just the content changes
3. However, almost all the files had their permission changed too and these are all showing up as modified in git (about 1000 files in total)
4. Majority of them are due to permission changes as I could not see any additions/deletions in my editor
5. For the commands above, the error I keep getting is `error: unrecognized input`, something to do with `git apply`, but I can't seem to nail the root cause
6. I also tried `git config core.fileMode false` and that did not hide the modifications either
7. My git is `git version 2.34.1`

Any idea what I'm missing here?

`git add .` solved the problem for me, but I would like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Show the output of `git status` (truncate file lists if necessary) and let us know which OS and filesystem you are using.