# View permissions change in Git

Tags: git

Before I commit some files, how can I see the file permission changes to files? I have some files that git status says had changed and should be added to commit but git diff doesn't show anything.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of permissions are you asking about?

Comment: File read, write and execute permissions. I'll update the question.

Comment: Git only tracks if a file is executable or not.

Comment: @Arrowmaster No, it tracks the full set of Unix file permissions. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737673/how-to-read-the-mode-field-of-git-ls-trees-output)

Comment: @Abizern: While all the output shows full unix file permissions, trust me when I say that 755 and 644 are the only possible permissions it will show. If you don't believe me test it for yourself.

Comment: yep - I was trying it for myself and can see it. My bad.

Comment: Dude, changing the question after it's been answered is not a good thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, since the question has been edited to ask something different, here's a different answer:

`git status -v` will list mode changes as well as diffs. You can filter this down to just mode changes by running it through grep with a context filter: `git status -v | grep '^old mode' -C 1` (sample result below)

```
diff --git a/matrix.cc b/matrix.cc
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Answer (score 26):

`git log --summary` will get you what you're looking for, I think. The flag will, *"Output a condensed summary of extended header information such as creations, renames and mode changes."* Note the example below:

```
$ git log --summary
commit 8978a03a209d1cc4842a8ff14b00253cb7744895
Author: Me
Date:   Wed Feb 23 12:43:30 2011 -0500

    second

 mode change 100644 => 100755 matrix.cc

commit e559dcbee268448d4185854c056174dcb87d3013
Author: Me
Date:   Wed Feb 23 12:43:10 2011 -0500

    first

 create mode 100644 matrix.cc
```

Comment: I changed the question a little, sorry about that.

Comment: apparently the question is asking how to check permission change before committing 
but regardless of that, [Eugen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465858/11190169) is better overall, since you dont need to commit to see the changes

Answer (score 12):

A straightforward answer to your question:

```
git diff --summary
```

will output something like this:

```
mode change 100644 => 100755 assets/README.md
mode change 100644 => 100755 assets/css/app.css
mode change 100644 => 100755 assets/js/app-monitor.js
mode change 100644 => 100755 assets/js/app.js`
```

Comment: And this `git diff --summary | grep --color 'mode change 100644 => 100755' | cut -d' ' -f7 | xargs chmod -x` would remove the execute bit so git doesn't see the files as changed. ref. https://wiki.freephile.org/wiki/Git/hacks#Ignore_File_Mode

Answer (score 4):

I used this

```
git status --porcelain=2 | grep '100755 100755 100644' | cut -d' ' -f9
```

you can change the three masks 100755 100755 100644 with ones you are looking for