# How to interprit git create mode message

Tags: git, msysgit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read the mode field of git-ls-tree’s output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737673/how-to-read-the-mode-field-of-git-ls-trees-output)
>   [What does ‘git commit’ mean when it says ‘create mode …’ on stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521938/what-does-git-commit-mean-when-it-says-create-mode-on-stdout)

I've added some files to git and I get the following message:

```
create mode 100644 file.txt
```

Obviously, 644 is the unix file permissions. What does the 100 portion mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8347325

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521938

Comment: We definitely need better search on the site ;) I voted to close my question as a duplicate.