# create tree without using staging area

Tags: git

In the [git internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) chapter of `git-scm` book there is an example of how git tree can be created:

`Git normally creates a tree by taking the state of your staging area or index and writing a series of tree objects from it. So, to create a tree object, you first have to set up an index by staging some files.`

And then they list commands that I can use to create the tree. My question is whether I can create a tree without using index (staging area)? For example instead of doing this:

```
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 83baae618... test.txt
```

Use something like this:

```
git create tree --add --cacheinfo 100644 83baae618... test.txt
```

**Update** based on Ismail Badawi's anser:

```
$ echo 'making tree' | git hash-object -w --stdin
07dae42a0730df1cd19b0ac693c6894a02ed6ad0
```

and then

```
$ echo -e '100644 blob 07dae42a0730df1cd19b0ac693c6894a02ed6ad0 \maketree.txt' | git mktree
fatal: input format error: 100644 blob 07dae42a0730df1cd19b0ac693c6894a02ed6ad0 \maketree.txt
```

Comment: `git mktree` to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git mktree`, like this:

```
echo -e "100644 blob 83baae618...\ttest.txt" | git mktree
```

(You need to write `echo -e` because of the literal tab. This is a shell thing, not a git thing).

Note this creates a tree that only points to `83baae618`, so it's not exactly the same as your `update-index` invocation, which adds to the index (which typically already points to other things). You can pass multiple lines to `git mktree`, each line describing one blob or tree.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the solution but received `input format error`. Please see my udpated

Comment: @Maximus You need a tab (`\t`) after the SHA, not a space. `07dae42a0730df1cd19b0ac693c6894a02ed6ad0\tmaketree.txt`

Comment: Hey, I've got one more question, how can I add a tree\file to an existing tree? Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Maximus Objects in git are immutable (because changing the content would change the hash). You would instead create a new tree with the old tree's content plus whatever you want to add. You can use `git ls-tree` to list the contents of a tree in a format `git mktree` understands and mess with the output to make the changes you want, or you can use the index -- `git read-tree` to read a tree's content into the index, make your changes (`git add` etc), then `git write-tree` to make a new tree.

Comment: Great, thanks for you elaborate answer! I've managed to add second tree to the first when creating first :). Do you where I can read about those permissions that I specify when creating a tree, e.g. 100644 for blobs, 040000 for tree?

Comment: @Maximus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737673/how-to-read-the-mode-field-of-git-ls-trees-output

Comment: Appreciate! So basically 100644 says that blob corresponds to a regular file which can be read and written by user. And since blobs are immutable, I'm guessing that those permissions are used when checking out a working tree to set permissions to files\directories corresponding to trees entries, correct?