# git fatal - the remote hung up unexpectedly but not RPC or permission or broken pipe related message

Tags: git, git-push, git-fsck

I have seen many post here on SO about git fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly issue but none of them seem to be related to mine.

All posts about this error on here are related to RPC, permission, broken pipe etc but the fatal error I get does not mention any of these.  It looks just like below

[image]

I went to github page and I noticed big red warning at the top telling me to change my password, so I thought that could be the problem.  I changed password and then tried again to push my local branch to remote (this branch was never pushed to remote before), but then I get following error

[image]

The above shows that an object with SHA=997ea57135c8343d4e062b673b1cf09cb65f9edf is having duplicate file entries so I wanted to see what the object is and it shows me number of duplicates like below:

```
dinosmbp:SquirrelFOH dinob$ git show 997ea57135c8343d4e062b673b1cf09cb65f9edf
tree 997ea57135c8343d4e062b673b1cf09cb65f9edf

.gitignore
.gitignore
Publishing/
Publishing/
SquirrelFoH.ipa
SquirrelFoH.ipa
SquirrelFoH.sln
SquirrelFoH.sln
SquirrelFoH/
dinosmbp:SquirrelFOH dinob$
```

I havent seen this before so I searched bit online and found how to issue `git fsck --full` and get:

```
dinosmbp:SquirrelFOH dinob$ git fsck --full
error in tree 0137ab90aeee240379136b822fce2c021b2ce1a0: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 02d112e8af95964cbbaee8763177826636291086: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 04150d134087d2b28e7e8249e2b0b90fac1f095b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 047def9b30f4403b2ae5d79d6d6353e3ef875bf4: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 06b790d9ba539bb6dd6348f5419b3cf04c1d7fb9: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 0870312ba37d1af6d57aff5d6e8dce379ffa4369: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 0963aaeee0ea0bf161ed09b5724f771bda03c18b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 0a4e9aaf2e465bd67b1f5b36b6ec0cf286821e6b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 0ee901e3ac610d53f02a276389b41eff8b14bc84: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 0f54d177dc9f3b497afefbffb6fd907d8e705c70: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 0fa52886e99e405e45ec1f86dbdefa2ca5992a5f: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 108b796f7d07385897855c7fcc702db0d35f2023: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 1113716a5b1ee7849825467fa5acc93b8b8b5b1f: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 11cd96f2ab97cdb5f0a4fe88f5d4798f8f1a8a9d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 13f9eb56b9e0ed9a78d1a24a85238feb4f02aa63: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 1317c16304ab8d329b2f9204759f9d9f060f30f8: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 163bd90808985c9e103794b03ba8531311a1c66c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 1dc1cd847c5fbad09f34751bd80e2c38c5a81785: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 1e85beafa87f00deb69c2ccf1833cf80d535eea7: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 1f1deb251016035e9e4773cf1b902d86fd7c9cff: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 225b2844e3db6b5e20327d7dbd8e005ecfeea98f: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 226c16b95c89970c5fc22fb94f7b7da3f6ac5652: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 23b2d43c1afadfba8a79f99538960079702d5f37: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 27b496cdc344fae4803c138dd47155578d28a36f: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 29f93c8346d4a60fb68cb878f9658b35bb54ca7c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 2d8d0f29eb94bdc1921bd34b86101dbd4b917ab6: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 2de80eeb8467cfc30392db827cf9823621699cf4: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 32880b4f342b73ca94166501ecd618d9abaebda7: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 35f6fa81260d8af2d53685d484cf8555ff13f0a6: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 38a5412baacafeeae53401c5a30af80e29cbce86: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 3a2a6510f2f81aa1eb7c98e3374be96e2375f157: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 3b789afb1191243f437c2d06df94e5f75e6dad67: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 404e17487485aec8ccbdb78a48c292b1e457d959: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 4545b158a7a5275fd64c84f310fa9b74ff1b904e: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 4681df0142985186ba962a207da1a2bd4a473767: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 479be2ba6db7978a3e4d208f965e4209cd3c3d3d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 485ab09fbd5f8a9e01295ab901dbc6e01a82cddc: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 4abc555c78e0bc6522a08b6931f92ccd4a169bf2: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 51593be4ae31c4c6a04c04f24682e4229b40bbb0: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 530cc1e5898777a58aa4188873a95d17cf922b1a: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 54793044163f01109adf0234a745fcd8d83e122b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 566c906c885d28844aacb5d69587f573f3bdf9fb: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 578613b2fd584335ffccdb3f5424f1914775c8e4: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 58c5d1f97bcdffd599f0daa0f4fe09532ba366f6: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 5b462757411cbdacadf341e4767ac395c188fc00: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 64103b61e1ec0650fc93026bb07ec7bbb6199df5: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 640eaf4ff9b2c3f96a0b766dc6a75b7ba9840c23: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 67627ab9f52bd876845ee2523a07c6dad92c5c0b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 6cc9f01ed50c53378d09224e9177e30c96310d0f: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 6f9114b352212d9f2a07710e10f3e30d3c3acfbc: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 70c9d9b6ffe31847486701ad317b6e9199e311e3: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 78e0e150ab602cbedb4edccd1a028d18bddcca8e: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 7a0c60ebda14bb63e6b6fc5bca5ccf6465fc65ca: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 7bd195f42041f2f2d40115eddebfeac89d622624: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 7b7c4639860381f8358e5c8019cd05e62449a22c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 7c3dd24b07fc6b5229ee732a8442e499689b1cbf: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 7d884741dcbeb8cb79c3431068efa054944ee2af: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 87fed062f333865b9559fbdc361edac552374829: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 89ee337e6fbc1216bee6f9d4c82182eacca0be6c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 8a50a76b801eecb1f12b6997ef4ce39510223613: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 94dacec179fe648c54e1783d5a695ca504dcf7cb: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 96ea661a8d55ae54a7abe85a13ea09fc9c32e4e7: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 997ea57135c8343d4e062b673b1cf09cb65f9edf: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 991ee965222565a44735a8d6adeddce2394d4cfc: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 9aba986821a2d53b8d93c1067acaa5ce8cab8e6e: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 9c092b53b13a295c832a6f9ca6b77aa8ab4f72df: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree 9e10bb95494ac40882462c3f1c9f3171ea14d431: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree a0078d938aa0794f40e46339ffb58e79c480e68c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree a0f228998e038adc992a78af37dd52de1163330a: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree a19485a4d83da642884f0f77e1421f23085400aa: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree a11c8181094d8c7c243166e14c9292a8699ada01: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree a9d50627fad4e1e3ab20ace157a0fe236a1aadf3: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree b210de6791fe1fa87ec753d8ee902fb0f8dcf3e7: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree b294ef3028bcfb47034bad331893e0b93237ca2d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree b711ea4cee58bb0a98b846ce13a555733bd349e2: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree b8d0feb095404887c7489ca79aeadb5373f7a0b6: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree bb9285400ec78e799cc2fb2e019b91569d3d7c6b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree bca5a305862677172167c1ad59d5c6640433645f: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree bc165ae40dc39056d923b2e563512916c4ab3892: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree bde57605d0fdfd9572f60dfa154a55b1fc6aa023: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree c41df20d2bbb48e33f5298f67de288b098c9eb18: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree c4421cd7c7029ba442ce8488bfe7a64f47c01768: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree c923fa16e137764155e201d8a8fda79546c05c2d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree c95fb7273dcaf2976fd7b1482aa1dc31b500c8ff: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree c950104cbc242dc82fd3f87f7e8c699b2a9cb1df: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree ca698504f8d25a1e291158d33a688b4ec1dbaa2b: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree cf92ed3b715c85c10a51c93347e1afef8ba38f7c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree d0eadfdb230184d500bcd86c1821c8f459e910bb: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree d3f0c998fa01f1047573248b7e56e94d5387792c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree d54bb658f3d32b6d535b0dca698071cb994af3d1: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree dae0e9e43163a54609b5cf752e641ea577a50b52: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree db14996cbe2e19ae23861cca0a7caafc1d4d3c81: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree e0f63423beaca3eb7db3762148e35a99a4e1934d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree e0a4162fe5a91d11b122040a134752121a8017f0: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree e018ec6c5d361328008601cad280f98aab615605: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree e07867fc893c14d9865db8a37fb66b9d2e1b3e87: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree ea2591e21dfe4ce27bc1ab6ebfd2052f954b0630: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree ec13595d66e6217c507d34e6db7e34adf45f9a6c: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree ee222b5429eac6faac1e4c0f69fd2a34ffa68e1d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree ef09433c073928df12e4f2db2e8b940b84770d0f: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree f0017897322dd181afb00dae2817c7a2cc8224ee: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree f1b512328b3e00176da6a80a13461ff723381b30: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree f56029e0033d02939b6580baaaf5fc9455ca11d7: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree f7ccf6fe79de7aeb78df58fcbdef5eb5bec5f6b4: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree f85a445c1be28476e79451588790a43c7e8ccfce: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree f92761e3a246f9ed5a612fdeb554adf778c9df1d: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree fc7614f53ff421f9a2dc32553afc5df0d6960afa: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree fd21c3dd3d9a87680fdff031058a6b478e7d64a2: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree fdd630509106b474d515601f9bc87b02511f0850: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
error in tree fe7257322ee276512ef4134816aacc2f54e9009a: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (27875/27875), done.
dangling blob ba0807ba5757149380fce28fdabee1da2bf00066
dangling blob 310e2252813f850b1ef58603a36e6ac2fb44e2cd
dangling blob e60fedf120b0d6bcf82f1a8059cd43d12b9b3563
dangling blob ea1081e4daf36b1a8f82bd044bdc4f46314361c9
dangling blob 931dadb0125f72cc47acb3d5ed25fc850e213eef
dangling blob c81f5b8423933407b0df3bf1345a16945cb65972
dangling blob 702329c7b876fa2555931eb1fb889bad8be958ab
dangling blob 6828a4e7e5e110ec9caf352386709ebe0596cce7
dangling blob b73855cc5aaaf6ae51f128837adbcbe5fbb3d4c3
dangling blob 8841f2da6c12f93c5437e861f76302b6087f303f
dangling blob 0d54abd97042b143dd264af01e07e255381a9bc2
dangling blob 25606dc05cee9a267f4e6438fa1894bfc2f46c48
dangling blob 1a6cddbf2603866b736022af714676b2179bd0d9
dangling blob 4c73be75d5528e952d3f3ccfbfae76322bd94599
dangling blob 2f770c7e411451cedfe4530bd6aeb42ccd36ee59
dangling blob d278f09400afc1d4ada5615195b92564d8aabbde
dangling blob c87c20fcf6c4baeefa6ecec7e396d7539e9c42e4
dangling blob ff8a50f06408c07cb2a248c69f8521071ef324da
dangling blob 8195320b293a426905c61775c5d11fd4f6542923
dangling blob 9a976ccfe320e3031e1eb29423ff0e8948b5c89b
dangling blob 7ba407761c7654a0c73b7233c5728c9851e9b128
dangling blob d3ac3979040026545384b567d04110437dcc9a67
dangling blob 93b17d8177d26deb4e9b3d406c266e339f6e8f8d
dangling blob 5ec101b26219b4dac66733a9ceb7720f3a296f75
dangling blob 0fc4dc2b0ba8de29a2557ae0b27f9c45adf0be5b
dangling blob 83c4b981d7fa88f036c39f45fd72017c861baa16
dangling blob b9c5779d978dfdd28f793b3814be6f4c43da6a74
dangling blob 55c60718ccc4f31a5d77723adec0dfa58edc667b
dangling blob 88cf064ff3e768851fa5a7a7d7cea9953b090fa1
dangling blob ecd18a78039f7d07d19bfc18107c8c3f23fdf775
dangling blob b2d4a73db6803161d4b182626f789400c30950ec
dangling blob 80d682a8b2c70f2158833df8e3b96e9d83277513
dangling blob 82d8256bda7f35d863a3060c5d01b27857a99a4c
dangling blob 4ddcec7ae977c210a06c790d43f39c700b042ec1
dangling blob 24dd049001b5e08e9c49c8955e1e887573f3c5e1
dangling blob 27e472c45b96bb0f4ed2b739c88bb2e543a892e4
dangling blob cdeb70c789ce6b7c42e53abdc3f26b1620b0592c
dangling blob 85ec4755467bea1ebfb48f81ca5eada9e9c0ffab
dangling blob 38edc88f59b5f654a25f10871dcf473bf7edadd5
dangling blob 2cee84209ff7029abba4485fb8bf6e9ab4579bc9
dangling blob fff70c752b704bc38cb8ad2e3be88ecdc23dbbe6
dinosmbp:SquirrelFOH dinob$
```

Answer (score 1):

The message in the latter case is because your Git objects are malformed. GitHub runs an fsck (consistency check) when accepting objects, and one of your tree (directory) objects contains multiple entries for the same file. Git wouldn't know how to check out such a tree entry: should it use the former entry, or the latter?

If you're using software other than Git itself to commit in your repository, you should report this issue to the makers of that software, since it's likely that software is writing bad data. Hopefully the makers of that software can give you tips for fixing the issue.

As for fixing this problem on your own, you could try to fix your branch with a force rebase. If you pick the branch from which your current branch was created, say `master`, you can then write `git rebase --force master`. That should cause Git to rebase your commits, and hopefully it will rewrite the tree objects that were corrupt.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am using git from the terminal on Mac. I do have SourceTree installed as well but I use SourceTree only to visualize what changed in files when I do my work, not to stage, commit, pull or push.

Comment: Is there any more info you can provide/elaborate?  I already merged my branch with develop using merge, not rebase.  Is applying rebase force still an option and if it is I guess I apply it from my branch (above that is feat/hi-merge)?  Thanks

Comment: You can try to use `git rebase -fr` to fix your branch and recreate the merge, but it requires a relatively recent Git to do so.