# Are git object mode numbers in a tree object arbitrary?

Tags: git

Are the numbers for mode (e:g 120000 for link, 100644 for file) are arbitrary or is there any reason for choosing that number?

Comment: Thanks..This is what I am looking for.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8347325/1831920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not arbitrary, but they are an artifact from when it was expected that Git would store Unix permissions for its contents.

On Unix, "644" is a common default permission for files.  It means that the owner has read-write access, and other users have read-only access.  Symbolic links do not have permissions, so "000" is used instead.

One exception -- "755" is used for executable files, and this is how Git stores that information.