# What does `git ls -files` output?

Tags: git

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 d88791dfb9168a50c6b91c0256dafc00c4c882f1 0   README
100644 fde330c39bee930b2de3410844097b416e7d9af4 0   branchfile
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   common/placeholder
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   reader/placeholder
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   writer/placeholder
```

What does the first column in the output mean?

With `--stage`, it outputs the files in the index.
WIthout `--stage`, what files will be outputted?

```
$ git ls-files 
README
branchfile
common/placeholder
reader/placeholder
writer/placeholder
```

Comment: First column is apparently file mode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ls-files+--stage+mode

Comment: It might be better to ask separate questions about `git ls-files --stage` vs `git ls-files` without `--stage`, since the output is for different sets of files in some cases. Or just read Git's own documentation carefully.

Answer (score 2):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#_output

> git ls-files just outputs the filenames unless --stage is specified in
> which case it outputs:
>
> [tag] mode object stage file

the first column is a mode in the mentioned case
you can find more about how to read the mode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8347325/4311135)

without the  `--stage` it lists all the tracked files

Comment: Thanks. What does `100644` translates to? How about my second question?

Comment: The values shown are the 16-bit file modes as stored by Git, following the layout of POSIX types and modes:
Type|---|Perm bits