# How to check if a file in git commit is a symbolic link without checkout

Tags: linux, git, github, gerrit

Is there a way to check if a file in git commit is a symbolic link without checking out the commit content?

**Background:**
There is a hook which is used to check C++ code formatting in each git commit that is pushed.
So far the algorithm is:
Get a list of files in a commit with `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=d -r ${commit}`.
Processes each file (content) in git commit, selected based on a file extension, using `git show ${commit}:${file}`.

**Problem:**
A file with `.cpp` extension may be a symbolic link, in which case it shall not be processed.

NOTE: I know that having source files as a symbolic link is not a good idea.

Comment: If you run the command "file" on the list of files, it will return details as whether the file is symbolically linked or not.

Comment: @RamanSailopal You cannot run `file` on an object in a non-checked out commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791647/7976758: `git ls-tree COMMIT-ID path-to/file` and look for the 1st column (mode); symbolic links have mode `120000`. See modes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/737877/7976758